# Making an iOS browser, how is this menu called?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, menu, xcode4.5

I am making an iOS web browser in Xcode 4.5 but I want one of the menus to look somewhat like this.  How is this menu called and how do I make one? 
The image is here:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

That is a UIActionSheet.

You can read more here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Here is a nice tutorial: http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/04/14/iphone-uiactionsheet-example/

Answer (score 1):

You can try the new open source [ShareKit 2.0](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit).

The information is at https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit.git

Comment: Please provide more detail in your post, if your link ever breaks this post won't help future users.